# Looking for a kids' sci-fi book about an alien on the Moon, with colour dot style pictures

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, moon

The book was likely published before the 1990s, and is about a lone alien on the Moon. It features colour dot style pictures, with some text.
Any ideas what the title might be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Your description of the book is extremely brief, though. Please take a look at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to include any more details that you can think to add. The more info you can provide about the book, the greater the chance that someone can ID it for you.

Comment: By "color dot style pictures," do you mean pointillism? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointillism

Comment: Was it story or novel? What was the colors (Moon, alien)? What was that alien doing?

Comment: Possible dot-style is about big pixels? Just like in games https://graphicriver.net/item/crystals-area-on-alien-planet-pixel-art-game-location/24958922

Comment: @Buzz +1 for that comment. I wonder also if Jim bob means "in the style of an [Ishihara test  color plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishihara_test)"?

Comment: Like colour dot matrix printer appearance. It was a story book with pictures and I believe the alien was on a journey. I think it was cool toned colours more

Comment: Possibly "The Lotus Caves"?  On the moon, there is a lone alien, discovered by two boys exploring further than they are allowed to go.  It has illustrations; I am trying to see whether those in an early printing match your description....

Comment: On the other hand, "The Lotus Caves" is a YA book, with more text than pictures.  If I understand your description, it was a younger children's book, with more pictures and less text?